# Dynamic SQL: How to Convert IN to several OR statements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, loops, dynamic-sql

Currently in SQL Server 2008 I am creating a Query:

```
SET @Query = 'select DISTINCT d.* from Device d ';

if @SerialNumbers <> ''
   SET @Query = @Query + 'WHERE d.SerialNumber in (Select * from [dbo].[Split] (''' + @SerialNumbers + ''', '',''))';
```

This solution does not work for me however, because I need to use `LIKE` rather than `IN`. I'd like the final SQL to look something like this..

```
select DISTINCT d.* from Device d 
WHERE d.SerialNumber LIKE 'row1 of select statement'
  OR d.SerialNumber LIKE 'row2 of select statement'
  OR ....
```

Where the select statement is as follows (it splits a string separated by commas and returns a 1 column table)

```
Select * from [dbo].[Split] (''' + @SerialNumbers + ''', '',''))
```

I am assuming there is a way to loop through the results of the select statement, but looping isn't set based. Does this matter, considering I'm building a query, which in the end will won't have any loops itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dynamic sql like this, but I think easier solution would be to use exists:

```
set @Query = 'select distinct d.* from Device d ';

if @SerialNumbers <> ''
   set @Query = @Query + 
       'where exists (
            select *
            from [dbo].[Split] (''' + @SerialNumbers + ''', '','') as s
            where d.SerialNumber like s.<column name> 
        )'
```